# Stomp java client

Tags: java, spring, stomp

I want to send an alerts to client if anything goes wrong in server side coding using STOMP Client. I have searched in google and didn't find any examples but I did find [STOMP client documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-client).

I have written following code in controller

```
WebSocketClient transport = new StandardWebSocketClient();
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
String url = "ws://localhost:8080/SpringMVCStompClient/alert";
StompSessionHandler handler = new MySessionHandler();
stompClient.connect(url, handler);
```

and MyHandler code is:

```
public class MySessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        Alert alert= new Alert();
        alert.setName("Server");
        alert.setMessage("Message from server");
        session.send("/topic/alert", alert);
    }
}
```

when i am trying to execute this execution is not going to MyHandler class. Is this is the right way to do?. 
Help he me how can i send a alert to client.

Websocket XML Configuration

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/alert">
            <websocket:sockjs/>
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
    </websocket:message-broker>
```

Controller

```
 @Autowired
    public SpringMVCController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

@MessageMapping("/alert")
@SendTo("/topic/alert")
public Alerts alerts(Alerts alerts) throws Exception {        
    Alert alert= new Alert();
    alert.setName("Server");
    alert.setMessage("Message from server");
    this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/alert", alert);

    return alerts;
}
```

Client js code service

```
(function(angular, SockJS, Stomp) {
  angular.module("alertApp.services").service("AlertService", function($q, $timeout) {

    var service = {}, listener = $q.defer(), socket = {
      client: null,
      stomp: null
    };

    service.SOCKET_URL = "/SpringMVCStompClient/alert";
    service.ALERT_TOPIC = "/topic/alert";
    service.ALERT_BROKER = "/app/alert";

    service.receive = function() {
      return listener.promise;
    };

    service.send = function(alert) {
      socket.stomp.send(service.ALERT_BROKER, { priority: 9}, JSON.stringify({
        message: alert.message,
        name: alert.name
      }));
    };

    service.disconnect = function() {
        socket.stomp.disconnect();
    };

    var startListener = function() {
      socket.stomp.subscribe(service.ALERT_TOPIC, function(data) {
          listener.notify(JSON.parse(data.body));
      });
    };

    service.initialize = function() {
      socket.client = new SockJS(service.SOCKET_URL);
      socket.stomp = Stomp.over(socket.client);
      socket.stomp.connect({}, startListener);
    };

    return service;
  });
})(angular, SockJS, Stomp);
```

Comment: why don't you simply use the SimpMessagingTemplate?

Comment: i have tried SimpleMessagingTemplate followed  this document [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-send). i didn't get any alert from server

Comment: can you update your question with configuration and client side code?

Comment: i have followed this tutorial [link](http://g00glen00b.be/spring-angular-sockjs/) and created chat app. Now i am trying to convert that chat app to generate alerts instead of chatting messages.

Comment: Thanks @Sergi SimpleMessagingTemplate is working for me.
What is the difference between sending message to client using SimpleMessagingTemplate and STOMP java client?

Comment: @Prasanth STOMP java client is used for communication with server not with other clients.